# RegEx to select first and last quote character

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to use RegEx to select the first and last quote character in values comma-separated in a string.

**What I got** with `/"((?!\s))/g`:

"Here is an "example" text" > `"`Here is an `"`example" text`"`

**What I need:**

"Here is an "example" text","Here is another "example" text" > `"`Here is an "example" text`"`,`"`Here is another "example" text`"`

Anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Your expected result is not clear. Please make it a little more clearer to help us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^"|"$|"(?=,")|(?<=",)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FIZI9a/1)

**Details**

- `^"` - a `"` at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `"$|` - a `"` char at the end of the string, or
- `"(?=,")|` - a `"` char that is immediately followed with a comma + `"`
- `(?<=",)"` - a `"` char that is immediately preceded with a `"` + comma.